# SAS Macro to Combine Municipal Proc SQL Statements Based on Date Criteria

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

I have a series of proc sql statements which pull data for Active, Inactive and Lapsed customers.  I end up with 3 tables.

- *Customers_Active
- *Customers_InActive
- *Customers_Lapsed

Active: 0-12M purchaser

Inactive: 13-24M purchaser, did not purchase 0-12M (active day range minus 12 months)

Lapsed:  25-36M purchaser, did not purchase 0-24M (inactive day range minus 24 months)

Again, In order to do this I have 3 separate proc sql statements and I start out by defining 6 macro variables.

I want to apply macro language so  I can uses  just 1 query to produce the 3 tables.

```
%let actstart = '24Feb2013'd;
%let actend = '22Feb2014'd;
%let iactstart = '26Feb2012'd;
%let iactend= '23Feb2013'd;
%let lapstart = '27Feb2011'd;
%let lapend = '25Feb2012'd;*
```

Here are the three statements

/*Active Table*/

```
proc sql;    
   create table Customers_Active as 
   select 
      household_id, 
      customer_id, 
      web_order_id, 
      transaction_date, 
      sku, 
      quantity, 
      original_price 
   from transaction_vw 
   where transaction_date >= &actstart and transaction_date <= &actend
   order by customer_id; 
quit;
```

/*Inactive Table*/

Notice I am not bringing in the customer_id which is already in the `Customers_Active` table.

```
proc sql;    
   create table Customers_Inactive as 
   select 
      household_id, 
      customer_id, 
      web_order_id, 
      transaction_date, 
      sku, 
      quantity, 
      original_price 
   from transaction_vw
   where transaction_date >= & iactstart and transaction_date <= &iactend
     and customer_id not in (select distinct customer_id from Customers_Active)
    order by customer_id; 
quit;
```

/*Lapsed  Table*/

Notice I am not bringing in the customer_id which is not already in the Customers_Active and the Customers_Inactive table.

```
proc sql;
   create table Customers_Lapsed as 
   select 
      household_id, 
      customer_id, 
      web_order_id, 
      transaction_date, 
      sku, 
      quantity, 
      original_price 
   from transaction_vw
   where transaction_date >= & lapstart and transaction_date <= & lapend
     and customer_id not in (select distinct customer_id from Customers_Active)
     and customer_id not in (select distinct customer_id from Customers_Inactive)
   order by customer_id;
quit;
```

To recap: the end result is 3 tables.

- *Customers_Active
- *Customers_InActive
- *Customers_Lapsed

•I'm pulling in the same vars for all three tables 
•Just the date range changes 
•In addition I don't want to include customer_id in the Customers_Inactive table which is already in the Customers_Active table 
•and customer_ids  in the lapsed table which are already in the Customer_Active and Customer_inactive tables

Again, since I'm pulling in the same vars I don't want to have three separate queries to do this just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in a bit different manner.  You can do it in a few ways, but maybe one SQL step and one datastep would be easiest.

```
proc sql;
  create table lookup_lastdate as 
    select customer_id as start, max(transaction_Date) as label,
      'LASTDATEF' as fmtname
    from transaction_vw
    group by customer_id;
quit;

proc format cntlin=lookup_lastdate;
quit;

%let today=11JUN2015;
data customers_active customers_inactive customers_lapsed;
  set transaction_vw;
  years = intck('YEAR',put(customer_id,LASTDATEF.),"&today."d,'c');
  if years < 1 then output customers_active;
  else if years < 2 then output customers_inactive;
  else if years < 3 then output customers_lapsed;
run;
```

`intck` with the `c` modifier at the end tells number of periods between two dates, so 1 year means between 1 year and 1 year 364 days.

The point of doing it this way is to use fewer passes through the data - so, first calculate how long last purchase was, then output their data.  It could be even more efficient than this in a DoW loop (which does 1 real pass and 2 virtual passes, assuming data fits in memory).   So we use a format to get it out (you could also join the tables if you like joins better, formats are just faster).  Then we compare that date using `intck` to see how many years have passed, and output to the appropriate file.

As a side note, there is a preference in SAS for not putting 3 files like this, but having 1 file and then adding a flag indicating which group it belongs to; then using `by` statements to do analyses on each group separately.  This simplifies the code further.  To do that, just change the `if` statements to set flags instead of outputting - or skip the `if` and just assign the year count directly.